# how to avoid blank screen between activities android?

Tags: android

When starting child activity from one activity tha second activity appears good.But in meantime blank screen appears.Why I don't know.Iam loading gps related data in oncreate() of second activity.How to avoid blank screen and load quickly.

regards,
Rajendar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you are performing a long running operation in `onCreate` then the application will take a long time to start.  There is no way around it.

As an alternative, could you move the long running code out of `onCreate` and into a background thread (as suggested by Fredrik Leijon), and in your `onCreate` method just pop up a `ProgressDialog` informing the user that the application is loading?  Once the thread is complete you can dismiss the dialog and load your normal view.

Comment: hey Dave please give me sample snippet.For example on MapActivity.Actually I commented total code of onCreate() still blank screen appears.I thought in my .xml file I declared Mapview using key.This is giving problem.how to solve like this xml loading problem.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the issue is now.  Your original question states that your view loads ok eventually, but shows a blank screen first.  Does it now not load at all?  Or does it still load, but just take a long time, even with onCreate() commented out?

Answer (score 3):

Change your activity launch mode such as  android:launchMode="standard".. Add this code in the corresponding activity which loads with black screen in your manifest file.. It solves your problem..

Comment: Thanks so much you saved me now i can sleep in peace ;)

Comment: `standard` is the default `launchMode`. Not sure why this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try loading the data in a separate thread

Comment: All the data related to View page.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to one of your activities in the Manifest file

**android:launchMode="standard"**

if you have activity that you want to have only one instance of it then use

**android:launchMode="singleTask"**